# Iterate over 36 million items in a list of tuples in python efficiently and faster

Tags: python, list, performance, numpy, iteration

Firstly, before anyone marks it as a duplicate, please read below. I am unsure if the delay in the iteration is due to the huge size or my logic. I have a use case where I have to iterate over **36 million items** in a list of tuples.  My main requirement is **speed and efficiency**. Sample list:

```
[
    ('how are you', 'I am fine'),
    ('how are you', 'I am not fine'),
    ...36 million items...
]
```

What I have done so far:

```
for query_question in combined:
    query = "{}".format(word_tokenize(query_question[0]))
    question = "{}".format(word_tokenize(query_question[1]))

    # the function uses a naive doc2vec extension of GLOVE word vectors
    vec1 = np.mean([
        word_vector_dict[word]
        for word in literal_eval(query)
        if word in word_vector_dict
    ], axis=0)

    vec2 = np.mean([
        word_vector_dict[word]
        for word in literal_eval(question)
        if word in word_vector_dict
    ], axis=0)

    similarity_score = 1 - distance.cosine(vec1, vec2)
    store_question_score = store_question_score.append(
        (query_question[1], similarity_score)
    ) 
    count += 1

    if(count == len(data_list)):
        store_question_score_descending = store_question_score.sort(
            key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True
        )
        result_dict[query_question[0]] = store_question_score_descending[:5]
        store_question_score =[]
        count = 1
```

The above logic aims to calculate the similarity scores between questions and perform a text similarity algorithm. ***I'm suspecting the delay in the iteration could be the calculation of `vec1 and vec2`.*** If so, how can I do this better? I am looking for how to **speed** up the process.

There are plenty of other questions similar to iterative over huge lists, but I could not find any that solved my problem.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: to assess this, pls post the code which can be run as [stand-alone - mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I assume the data is list of (question, answer) for multiple answers for a number of questions. If you have the freedom to restructure the data, a dictionary with questions as keys and lists or tuples of answers as values would be much more easy to iterate over.

Comment: I have basically found it is just the iterations that are taking long, 36 million iterations. Do u have any suggestions for iterating through a 36 million list or any other way of storing it for speeding things up?

Comment: There's a bunch of code after the `vec1` and `vec2` are computed, which I'm wondering about too. What does it do?

Comment: Calculates the average word embedding using GLOVE to calculate the similarity score between the two vectors

Comment: "I have basically found it is just the iterations".  I timed iterating over a 36 million-element list of two-tuples of string with `for item in items: pass`, and it took ~500ms.  So it is what you are doing in the loop that needs to be sped up.  Use a profiler as one of the answers suggested.  Shave off a microsecond, save 36 seconds.

Comment: Also, `query = `'{}'.format(word_tokenize(...))` converts whatever `word_tokenize` is (a list?) into a string, but later `ast.literal_eval(query)` converts it back.  BIG waste of time.  Same with `question`.  Just do `for word in word_tokenize(query_question[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try caching:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def compute_vector(s):
    return np.mean([
        word_vector_dict[word]
        for word in literal_eval(s)
        if word in word_vector_dict
    ], axis=0)
```

Then use this instead:

```
vec1 = compute_vector(query)
vec2 = compute_vector(question)
```

---

If the size of the vectors is fixed, you can do even better by caching to a numpy array of shape `(num_unique_keys, len(vec1))`, where in your case `num_unique_keys = 370000 + 100`:

```
class VectorCache:
    def __init__(self, func, num_keys, item_size):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = np.empty((num_keys, item_size), dtype=float)
        self.keys = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.keys
            return self.cache[self.keys[key]]
        self.keys[key] = len(self.keys)
        item = self.func(key)
        self.cache[self.keys[key]] = item
        return item


def compute_vector(s):
    return np.mean([
        word_vector_dict[word]
        for word in literal_eval(s)
        if word in word_vector_dict
    ], axis=0)


vector_cache = VectorCache(compute_vector, num_keys, item_size)
```

And then:

```
vec1 = vector_cache[query]
vec2 = vector_cache[question]
```

---

Using a similar technique, you can also cache the cosine distances:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def cosine_distance(query, question):
    return distance.cosine(vector_cache[query], vector_cache[question])
```

Comment: I am on python 3.7. Is that why I am getting an error while trying to import cache?

Comment: @AmalSailendran Ah probably. Try using `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` instead since it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: "TypeError: Expected maxsize to be an integer or None" when I try to import lru_cache. is there a size that we need to specify?

Comment: I don't see much of a difference, the MacBook's fan starts spinning fast when the iterations reach around 270,000. Nonetheless, appreciate the help!

Comment: I would say it's a bit faster!

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest to use line_profiler to make sure what takes the most time.

Add the decorator to function you want to profile and just run your script (possibly with smaller amount of data so it does not take too long).

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler

def do_profile(follow=[]):
    def inner(func):
        def profiled_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                profiler = LineProfiler()
                profiler.add_function(func)
                for f in follow:
                    profiler.add_function(f)
                profiler.enable_by_count()
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                profiler.print_stats()
        return profiled_func
    return inner

@do_profile()
def encapsulating_function():
    for query_question in combined:
        query = "{}".format(word_tokenize(query_question[0]))
        question = "{}".format(word_tokenize(query_question[1]))

        vec1 = np.mean([word_vector_dict[word] for word in literal_eval(query) if word in word_vector_dict],axis=0) #the function uses a naive doc2vec extension of GLOVE word vectors
        vec2 = np.mean([word_vector_dict[word] for word in literal_eval(question) if word in word_vector_dict],axis=0)
        similarity_score = 1 - distance.cosine(vec1,vec2)
        store_question_score = store_question_score.append((query_question[1],similarity_score)) 
        count+=1
        if(count == len(data_list)):
            store_question_score_descending = store_question_score.sort(key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
            result_dict[query_question[0]] = store_question_score_descending[:5]
            store_question_score =[]
            count = 1
```

(`do_profile` function copied from: https://zapier.com/engineering/profiling-python-boss/)

Can't help you further until you do that

Comment: I have basically found it is just the iterations that are taking long, 36 million iterations. Do u have any suggestions for iterating through a 36 million list or any other way of storing it for speeding things up?

Comment: @AmalSailendran Did you check which of the lines within that loop took the largest fraction of the time?