# iterating each item of one list with each item of another huge list efficiently and faster

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, iteration

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352533/iterate-over-36-million-items-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-python-efficiently-and-fast/67373005#67373005) for which I did not get any satisfactory answers. As such, I'll try to ask the question in a different way. I have two lists, one with **100** items, one with **370,000** items. I want to perform a logic by using each of the 100 items with each of the **370,000** items. if I used two for loops, it would mean ***370,000 * 100*** iterations which would take awfully long.

How can I store this in a better way? how can I speed up the process?

```
for item_one in len(100_item_list):
   for item_two in len(370000_item_list):
    '''do something with item_one and item_two'''
```

**My main requirement: speed and efficiency**

Comment: Please do not open another question of the same question even if you haven't gotten a great answer. Be patient.

Comment: That's not even the point, I wanted to put out my thoughts clearly when I understood my requirement better.

Comment: @12944qwerty It's totally fine (and recommended) to open a new question if the alternative is to significantly alter the question. Haven't checked if that's the case here, though.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details. If this is true: "I want to perform a logic by using each of the 100 items with each of the 370,000 items" then *there's no way around that*, unless you don't actually need to visit all those...

Comment: Thanks @MateenUlhaq, exactly what I meant

Comment: At first glance, the questions look similar. They may not be though...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need to do that. I am doing a text similarity approach wherein I need to calculate the cosine similarity scores of each question in listOne with that of listTwo questions. Therein, I can find the best matching question and return it. The question is how can I store it better or even iterate it different.

Comment: Your questions seems to be "How do I perform 37 million iterations without performing 37 million iterations?". Obviously the only way to do 37 million iterations is to actually do them.

Comment: Some ideas: swap the order of the iterations (sometimes helpful if it avoids duplicate intermediate computations), or cache some of the computationally heavy intermediate calculations. Also, is it necessary to compute all 370000*100 items? If you only need a fraction of those, you can compute on demand instead.

Comment: maybe if you have enough memory you can use a dataframe with the data from the two lists joined and try using `apply`. I didn't test if it is faster or not, but you tell us

Comment: @FrancoMorero that wouldn't help. `.apply` isn't magic, in fact, it is generally *slower* than a python-level loop (although recently I think it was sped up)

Comment: So, I would look into "space partitioning data structures" like [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and [ball trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree). The high dimensionality of your data will probably work against you, though. I've used [sklearn for this before](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#unsupervised-neighbors)

Comment: If you need speed and you need to iterate over the list that way (ie no better algorithm) and this is slow, then it is probably either because the actual computation you want to do is to much for your machine or simply that using CPython is not the good choice (assuming no better library that can be used here). CPython and more generally Python is clearly not made for high performance. You can try the PyPy JIT which target speed and is generally a bit faster or just rewrite this par of your code in C/C++ or at least Cython.